# Are there actually any polarised capacitors on the Arduino due?

Tags: arduino, pcb

I've been comparing the Arduino schematic to the real board and I cant seem to see any indication of polarised caps where they should be on the board. Have they just used regular ceramic caps instead? thanks

Arduino Schematic: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf
[image: Arduino Close up]

Comment: There's one in that photo.

Comment: Schematic wise, And any cap over 10uF is extremely likely to be electrolytic rather than ceramic regardless of whether the symbol is polarized or not. In that schematic lots of 10uF caps have a polarized symbol and I don't believe it with how rare tantalums are nowadays.

Comment: That's what I mean, there's obviously one polarised electrolytic cap at bottom of the image, but what is the rest? are they just unpolarised? there doesn't seem to be any tantalum caps on there.

Comment: Highly likely to be ceramics. Even a small electrolytic would still stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: If you're aware of a polarized cap, then you'll want to edit your question to ask something more specific and give context. Else the answer is a simple "yes".

Comment: This does not appear to be an electronic design question, but rather a query about a product.  If there is a *specific* capacitor you are wondering about, edit your question to show both its schematic depiction and a picture of the part on the board which you feel is incompatible with that depiction.

Comment: I think you'll find that between now and when the Arduino board was originally designed, the capacity of ceramic capacitors has improved to the point of older tandalinium capacitors have been replaced if there were any.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here you go. The black stripe indicates the negative terminal.

Answer (score 1):

See [Arduino Due (Open hardware)](https://easyeda.com/chenmanjia/Arduino_Due_Open_hardware-OoUcuoFXf#:%7E:text=The%20Arduino%20Due%20has%2054,button%20and%20an%20erase%20button.) for everything.

PC1 & PC2 are 47 μF Electrolytics.  Red circles.

[image]

Rest of polarized capacitors appear to be tantalums in Blue.

(μF C29,C1,C11,C3,C2,C33,C27,C35,C41 SMC_B).

[image]